# Scrapy does not find module 'attrs'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a website. I'm using scrapy with the following commands:

`pip install scrapy`

`scrapy startproject test && cd test`

`scrapy genspider test_spider www.webdomain.com`

`scrapy crawl test_spider`

this results in

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'attrs'
```

(full stacktrace can be found here: https://pastebin.com/177Vdpfk)

To resolve this, I ran `pip install attrs` with the following result:

```
$ pip install attrs                                                 
zsh: /usr/local/bin/pip: bad interpreter: /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: no such file or directory
Requirement already satisfied: attrs in /Users/rabdelazin/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (21.2.0)
```

So for some reason it seems that attrs is installed but scrapy does not find it. Any help appreciated.

Note: Googling for an answer yielded several results to similar questions with missing or unsatisfactory answers.

Comment: Have you tried installing in a virtual enviornment?

Comment: yes. both inside and outside of a virtual env i get the same issue.

Comment: Looks like Uninstalling scrapy and attrs then reinstalling scrapy did the trick. It looks like scrapy installs it's own version of attrs.

Comment: I deleted my answer because I looked at your pastebin and saw you were using anaconda so I was going to edit it with the conda information, but then I got distracted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

`pip uninstall scrapy attrs`
then
`pip install scrapy attrs`

or

`pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall attrs scrapy`

or if you are using `conda` then do the equivalent for it.

And if none of that works then your best bet is to uninstall and reinstall python.